# "Seguir" string switches to English when you follow a post on Portuguese SO

Tags: bug, localization, follow-post, portuguese-stackoverflow

Over at [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), when you click the "seguir" button (Follow) to follow a post:

[image]

It switches to the English "following":

[image]

Instead of showing "Following" in Portuguese.  The tooltip also shows mostly English:

[image]

Same for the "No longer following" tooltip:

[image]

If these strings aren't translated yet, can we add them to Transifex?  If they are, can we fix that?

Comment: Works fine on Spanish, so it's likely just never been translated before in Transifex. https://i.stack.imgur.com/trORm.png

Comment: @Catija yep, I saw that.

Comment: @Ollie you'll be speaking Portuguese in no time :D I knew you were an SE entrepreneur, now you're a polyglot entrepreneur.

Comment: @bad_coder It'll certainly help when fighting spam on those sites ;)